# Civicrm permissions for different departments

Tags: permissions

can anyone advise if civicrm supports permissions at department level for a business. So that all departments have access to create/edit an event within their department. They don't have access to events created in other departments? I am referring to Manageing the events for departments not signing up to events.

Can the roles be configured to allow this somehow?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

We have recently worked on an extension for a sports club association which means each club has officers who can create/edit events which are linked to that club, but not to other ones. It is not ready for publishing yet but will be something we will do if we think it can be made generic enough.

If you want to discuss them may be better to open a channel in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/

I am doing some digging to check what the scenarios are that it caters for and which it doesn't and what it might require to make it generic.

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/civicrm-permissions